# Velocity of a particle colliding with the surface of a pistone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, momentum, collision

I am trying to understand how the following result is true.

If we have a particle moving in x direction with velocity $v_1$ and a wall moving in the x direction with a smaller velocity $u$, the following for the x component of the velocity vector of the particle after the collision:

$$v_{1\text{(after)}}=-(v_1-2u)$$

I am trying to derive the same result but how can I do that, when the mass of the wall is different then that of the particle, and when we use the conservation of momentum, the mass of the wall is taken infinite big, and moreover it is not present in the above equation?

$$mv_{1\text{(before)}} + Mu= - mv_{1\text{(after)}} + Mu$$

When I try and solve this, I get a zero from one side. That is clearly wrong

Comment: Where does the *pistone* come in?

Comment: it represents the moving wall

Comment: @RogerVadim *Pistone* comes in as soon as the FBI is required https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_D._Pistone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an elastic collision, the speed of the elements is the same before and after only in the frame where the center of mass is at rest.

In that frame the objects have zero net momentum at all times.  The speeds are fixed unless they can dissipate KE, which is not possible for an elastic collision.  So the only change in this frame is that the directions reverse after the collision.

As you say, if we assume the piston is much larger, then the we just use the frame where the piston is at rest.

So the method is

- Shift to frame with COM at rest
- Reverse the velocity of the colliding objects
- Shift back to the original frame

Before the collision it has speed $v_1$, or in the piston rest frame, $v'_1 = v_1 - u$.  After the collision, it has the same speed but the opposite direction.  $v'_{1(\text{after})} = -(v_1 - u)$.  Then you shift back to the original frame.  $v_{1(\text{after})} = -(v_1 - u) + u = (v_1 - 2u)$

Comment: Is there a theory that I can read and understand all what you said? Like being able to comprehend this COM frame where both objects look like they are not moving? The shiftings etc? I don't understand the logic honestly

Comment: When you shift back to the original frame (which is "the original " frame?) why do you keep the expression of velocity that you found while observing the process in another frame ?

Comment: Here's a page that goes over some of the concepts.  http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/apphynet/dynamics/Collisions/elastic_cm.htm

Comment: I understand the first two expressions, but I don't get the 3rd one. Why do you keep that expression for the speed of the particle as it bounces back, even after you leave the reference frame in which the particle has the 2nd expression. You are changing the frame, that way of looking at the speed of the particle shouldn't be viable since you aren't in the same frame anymore, or no?

Comment: It's just a frame change.  To shift into the frame where the piston is fixed you subtract the velocity of the piston ($-u$).  To shift back you just add the velocity of the piston ($+u$).

Comment: Isn't this like me on a car with 20 km/h looking at another car coming towards me with 20 km/h, but for me in the reference frame of my own car, the opposite vehicle is moving with 40 while I am at rest. Now what you are doing in the 3rd expression, If I am not in the car frame anymore, but out on the road without moving, then I still consider the opposite car as moving with 40 km/h ? Or it's not like this?

Comment: In this one, you're on the road watching the car go by.  We *temporarily* shift to another frame to find the change in speed from the collision.  Then we shift back to determine what speed the person on the road sees afterward.